# If $X\times Y$ is compact then $X,Y$ are compact spaces

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

If $X\times Y$ is compact then $X,Y$  are compact spaces

---

Let  $X\times Y$ be non-empty compact space $U_i, i\in \{1,2,...\}$ be an open cover for $X\times Y$, we know that $U$ is open in $X\times Y$ iff $U=\bigcup_jV_j\times W_j$ where $V_j,W_j$ are open sets in $X,Y$ equivalent.

$X\times Y \subseteq\bigcup_i U_i \Rightarrow X\times Y\subseteq  \bigcup_i \bigcup_j V_{j_i}\times W_{j_i}$,

obvious that $\bigcup_i \bigcup_j V_{j_i}$ is an open cover of $X$, $π_1(X\times Y)\subset \bigcup_i \bigcup_j V_{j_i} $

because $X\times Y$ is compact, it exists a finite cover of $U_i $
and we get

$X\times Y \subseteq\bigcup_i^n U_i \Rightarrow X\times Y\subseteq  \bigcup_i^n \bigcup_j V_{j_i}\times W_{j_i}$

now if i take the projection $π_1(x,y)=x$ and $π_2(x,y)=y$
I get

$\underbrace{π_1(X\times Y)}_{=X}\subseteq π_1(\bigcup_i^n U_i)=π_1(\bigcup_i^n \bigcup_j V_{j_i}\times W_{j_i})=\bigcup_i^n \bigcup_j V_{j_i}$

thus, $X\subseteq \bigcup_i^n \bigcup_j V_{j_i}$

Comment: It isn't true that a set is open in the product if and only if it's the product of open sets.

Comment: No, that’s not correct. Open subsets of $X \times Y$ are more complicated that mere products of open subsets of $X$ and $Y$. You want to show that $X$ is compact, therefore you need to start with any open cover of $X$ and show it has a finite subcover.

Comment: A simpler argument: $X$ is a continuous image of $X \times Y$.

Comment: Also, the result as stated is not true because of $\varnothing \times Y=\varnothing$. It is true if you assume $X,Y$ non-empty.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path now that i edit it, is it correct ?

Comment: @Mindlack is my edited solution ok ?

Comment: It still has a little mistake I think, because I take the open cover of $X$ from the open cover of $X\times Y $, but I think it can still work.

Comment: by using the idea that $X\subseteq \cup V_i$, $Y\subseteq \cup W_i$ , ---> $X\times Y \subseteq \cup (\cup (V_i\times  W_i))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}\,$ and $\{W_{\beta}\}_{\beta\in B}\,$ be covers of $X$ and $Y$. Where $A$ and $B$ be indexing sets.

Then $\{U_{\alpha}\times W_{\beta}|(\alpha,\beta)\in A\times B\}$ is a cover of $X\times Y$ by basis elements .

Then as $X\times Y$ is compact there exists a finite subset $I\subset A\times B$ which can be then written as $\{(\alpha_{1},\beta_{1}),(\alpha_{2},\beta_{2}),...(\alpha_{n},\beta_{n})\}$ such that
$\{U_{\alpha_{i}}\times W_{\beta_{i}}|1\leq i\leq n\}$ covers $X\times Y$.

Now $\{U_{\alpha_{1}},U_{\alpha_{2}},...U_{\alpha_{n}}\}$ form a cover of $X$. and similarly the $W_{\beta_{i}}$'s  form a cover of $Y$.

Comment: Thank you for writing the proof, obvious much better idea than mine.

Comment: @lupusnox . I am also learning topology . I am a noob too lol. Not going to lie...topology has been one of the hardest topics to learn for me.

Comment: And btw @lupusnox . You are trying to prove compactness of $X$ using compactness of $X\times Y$. So you first have to start with a cover of $X$ and show that it has a finite subcover(which you do by using compactness of X x Y . You cannot start with $X\times Y$ first. Because then you are just proving that $X$ has a finite cover. That is of no use. The definition of compactness is that ANY cover has a finite subcover , not just one particular finite cover.

Comment: nitpick: to show the $U_{\alpha_i}$ form a cover of $X$ we need $ Y \neq \emptyset$ and vice versa. The assumption of non-empty spaces is often taken for granted....

Comment: Ah yes. @HennoBrandsma . I always botch up these small details. I am just a undergrad student.

Answer (score 1):

If neither $X$ nor $Y$ is empty and if $X$ is not compact, let $C$ be an open cover of $X$ with no finite sub-cover. Then $\{s\times Y: s\in C\}$ is an open cover of $X\times Y$ with no finite sub-cover.